# Assign a result from promise to an external variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I'm using promise to get a value from DB, and I want to search db for a value retrieved after a form submission (req.body.country), get its id and assign it to a variable declared out of the promise, how to get it?
Here's the code:

```
var newAddress = new Address(); // Address is a mongoose model.
newAddress.city = req.body.city;
newAddress.state = req.body.state;
Country
  .findOne({name: req.body.country})
  .then(function (result) {
    newAddress.country = result;
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    res.send(500, {message: 'Failed to search into DB'});
  });

newAddress.save(function (err, result) {
   if(err) {
     res.status(500).send('Failed to save the newAddress to DB: ' + err);
   }
});
```

This is the mongoose address model:

```
var addressSchema = new Schema({
  street1: {type: String, required: true},
  street2: String,
  city: String,
  state: String,
  zip: String,
  country: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Country'},
  lat: String,
  long: String
});
```

Everything is inside nested callbacks, I'm trying to move from callbacks to Promise.
I've no error, it simply doesn't save the country in the address as newAddress inside the promise is not the same newAddress declared at the code beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `newAddress.save()` method to `then` callback

```
var newAddress = new Address(); // Address is a mongoose model.
Country.findOne({name : req.body.country})
    .then(function (result) {
        newAddress.country = result;
        newAddress.save(function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send('Failed to save the newAddress to DB: ' + err);
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        res.send(500, {message : 'Failed to search into DB'});
    });
```

Please read more about `Promise`'s and how to return from async functions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I'm reading a lot about Promise, but I missed this completely. The code was really more complex, I'm trying to change from callbacks to promise

Answer (score 1):

1. Move address creation into the promise chain.
2. Don't mix callback-style and promise-style code (`newAddress.save()` returns a promise).
3. Use single `catch` handler to process all possible errors.

Code:

```
Country
  .findOne({ name : req.body.country })
  .then(country => {
    let address = new Address({
      city: req.body.city,
      state: req.body.state,
      country
    });
    return address.save();
  })
  .then(address => res.send(address))
  .catch(err => res.send(500, { message : 'Something went wrong', err }));
```

Comment: I've other assignements made to `newAddress` out of the premise, that's why I declared the var `newAddress` before the findOne function. Let me edit the question to better clarify it

Comment: You can do all this stuff inside `then` callback, check the updated answer.

Comment: I like the way everything is declared inside the `then` callback, but it doesn't work. for `city: req.body.city` it returns this error
_SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer_

Comment: What values have `req.body.city` and `req.body.state`?

Comment: they're string, got from form submission. I'll post the code in the question

Comment: What node.js version do you use? The problem can be in the `country` field, try `country: country`.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the `country.findOne` is inside a `User.findOne` callback? Anyway I should change the question to put all the nested callbacks I have, so maybe it's better I open another question

Comment: `country.findOne` is inside a `User.findOne` direct callback isn't wrong as such, but is typically less convenient than working with promise(s), which can be assigned (eg in the same scope as your `newAddress`), and you can access their delivered values via chained `then(s)`. For values delivered by separate promises (eg one for `user` and one for `country`), you can use `Promise.all(...).then(...)` to access the individual values in the same scope as each other.